# plotting a map of north greenland in R

Tags: r, mapinfo, maps

My knowledge in GIS and R is again tested when I want to map a small part of northern Greenland (called Washington Land) in R (and plot analysis data on top later).

I've managed to plot it with

```
library(maps)
library(mapdata)
library(rworldmap)
map("worldHires", "Greenland", xlim=c(-67,-63), ylim=c(78,82))
newmap <- getMap(resolution = "high")
plot(newmap, xlim=c(-67, -63), ylim=c(78,82), asp=1)
```

But resolution and projection is horrible for this area and my need.

I have a good map in MapInfo, but how should I output a map, so it can load in R and R can plot data accurately on top of it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the freely available Level 2 [GADM shapefile data for Greenland](http://www.gadm.org/country), which comes in EPSG:4326 (Lat/Lon projection) by default, and import it into R using the GDAL functionalities offered by the `rgdal` package. Then, define the geographic extent for Washington Land and crop the previously imported shapefile. Make sure you have all the required dependencies installed (e.g. `rgeos`)

```
# Required packages
library(rgdal)
library(raster)

# Import Greenland shapefile data
shp.greenland <- readOGR(dsn = "/path/to/shapefile/folder", 
                         layer = "GRL_adm2")

# Define cropping extent for Washington Land
ext.washington.land <- extent(-67, -63, 78, 82)

# Subset Greenland shapefile
shp.washington.land <- crop(shp.greenland, ext.washington.land)
```

**Update:**
Now, if you'd like to include glaciated areas, you could download e.g. the corresponding 10m shapefile from [Natural Earth](http://www.naturalearthdata.com/), import and crop it according to the predefined extent, and add it to your plot.

```
# Import glaciated areas
shp.glaciers <- readOGR(dsn = "/path/to/shapefile/folder", 
                        layer = "ne_10m_glaciated_areas")

# Subset (and plot) glaciated areas by extent of Washington Land
shp.glaciers <- crop(shp.glaciers, ext.washington.land)

plot(shp.washington.land, col = "darkolivegreen3")
plot(shp.glaciers, col = "azure", add = TRUE)
```

[image: Washington Land glaciated]

Comment: It looks better yes. I'm having a small issue with the code. It says it can't find the "shp.adm2" file. I can't see it in the downloaded files either?

Comment: Ah, sorry for that. I just forgot to rename a variable in the above code. Now it should work (:

Comment: great, but now I realize that there is no inner boundary from the inland ice which pose a problem. Does gadm files include this data, and how do I inspect/explore the gadm shp file?

Comment: See above update. What information do you need about the shapefiles?